# How to get animation but still hide ol?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my ordered list, i want a animation but i also want the ordered list to be hidden. when the list is not open there is a gap between the lists.

so my question is: How do i make the ordered list `display: none` and still get an animation when closing it. How do get the list to be closed as standard?

```js
function loadul(name) {
  var elem = $('#' + name);
  if (elem.hasClass('show-list')) {
    elem.removeClass('show-list');
    elem.addClass('hide-list')
    elem.data('height', elem.outerHeight())
    elem.css('height', '0px')
  } else {
    elem.removeClass('hide-list');
    elem.addClass('show-list')
    elem.css('height', elem.data('height'))
  }
}
```

```css
.sub-list {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

.hide-list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<li id="work" OnClick="loadul('list1')">
  List
</li>
<ol class="sub-list show-list" id="list1">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>

<li id="work" OnClick="loadul('list2')">
  List
</li>
<ol class="sub-list show-list" id="list2">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Why don't you try bootstrap accordion for this?

Comment: The `ol` is hidden in your example...? Also note that your HTML is invalid as you cannot have an `li` outside of a `ul` or `ol`, and you're repeating `id` attributes.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan When a list closes it dont get the animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default bootstrap `.collapse` class for this collapsing.

Bootstrap collapse comes with default slide animation

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="lists">
  <span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">List Number 1</span>
  <ul id="demo" class="collapse">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="lists">
  <span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">List Number 2</span>
  <ul id="demo1" class="collapse">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Love it, exactly what i needed ;D

Comment: I'm glad you find this helpful. Have a nice day :D

Answer (score 0):

As @Viira commented to your question it looks like you could use jQuery accordion for this (since you already include jQuery). I made an example with your data here: https://jsfiddle.net/kr4qhy9m/.

Html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>List 1</h3>
  <div>
    <ol>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <h3>List 2</h3>
  <div>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

Comment: I thought I was the one commented that >_<

Comment: @Viira Sure! :D BTW The accordion needs to be collapsed by default, right?

Comment: That's our wish if we want that to be collapsed by default we can add `.active` class to the responding ul

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `display:none` you can animate `min-height` for `ul` I have added `min-height` for the animation I have changed your `html` because it was not valid

```js
function loadul(name) {
  var elem = $('#' + name);
  if (elem.hasClass('show-list')) {
    elem.removeClass('show-list');
    elem.addClass('hide-list')
    elem.data('height', elem.outerHeight())
    elem.css('height', '0px')
  } else {
    elem.removeClass('hide-list');
    elem.addClass('show-list')
    elem.css('height', elem.data('height'))
  }
}
```

```css
.sub-list {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 300ms;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.hide-list {
  min-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="work" OnClick="loadul('list1')">
    List
  </div>
  <ol class="sub-list show-list" id="list1">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div>
  <div id="work" OnClick="loadul('list2')">
    List
  </div>
  <ol class="sub-list show-list" id="list2">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: If you close bouth lists there is a gap thats my problem now

Comment: using min-height will still cause issues when it comes to responsive view